# how to send message to specific user using SignalR

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

I just upgraded SignalR from v 0.53 to 1.0.1 and found oput that IConnectionIdGenerator interface that i weere using to set clientIds on connect does not longer exsist (which made me sad).

Now the question is, how do i get around this problem?

How do i send a message to specific user (or set of users) without being able to set each specific users connection ID??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the previous versions of SignalR but with the the version v1.0.1 you may send messages (call Javascript methods) on client from within your `Hub` using the `Clients` property.

For example:
`Clients.Caller.addMessage(data);` - sends a message to the caller client.
`Clients.All.addMessage(data);` - sends a message to all clients.
etc. (Check the [HubConnectionContext](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/HubConnectionContext.cs) class).

If you need to maintain groups of clients, use the `Groups` property.

You can also maintain your custom groups using the `Context.ConnectionId`.

For detailed information you can have a look at the [SignalR Wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) page.

Hope this helps you further.